# How do I ensure the UDPClient Receive Callback processes the message on a separate thread?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, udpclient

I am trying to figure out how to separate the UDPClient receive callback from the processing of the received message. Due to the high volume of UDP messages coming in, we want to shift the actual processing of the message to another thread, hoping to take the weight off the UDP Client and not miss any of the incoming messages. (200 messages / second)

Does the AsyncCallBack occur on the same thread the UDPClient is on or a new thread? If it is on the same thread, then if I create a new thread inside the callback, I would be creating a separate thread per message which wouldn’t work.
If the AsyncCallback is on the same thread as the connection, then my thinking is I would have to somehow create a thread prior to making the connection, then invoke something on that thread for each message received?

```
Private Sub OpenConnection()
    _ipendpoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _configobj.port)
    _udpclient = New UdpClient(_ipendpoint)
    _udpclient.BeginReceive(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub ReceiveCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = _udpclient.EndReceive(ar, _ipendpoint)
    _udpclient.BeginReceive(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReceiveCallback), Nothing)
    ProcessReceived(bytes)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessReceived(bytes() As Byte)
    Dim rcv As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes).Trim()
    'PROCESS MESSAGE ON DIFFERENT THREAD
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating things a bit. 200 messages per second is nothing.

First of all you need a reading loop:

```
while (true) {
 var result = udpClient.Receive(...);
 Task.Run(() => ProcessPacketAsync(result));
}
```

This is all it takes. You need to implement `ProcessPacketAsync`. Depending on what that function does you need to make it use async IO. Often, synchronous IO is enough. The main reason to use async IO is to save threads when there is a great amount of concurrent operations.

You asked what threads these things run on. This does not matter but the answer is: On some thread pool thread.

Comment: Right but the thing is our process operation is very heavy and involves array enumeration, which is why 200 messages can get heavy and needs to be processed in a separate thread.

Comment: Right, Task.Run accomplishes that. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, marking the answer now. Do you think it's crazy to create 200 threads / sec, if each created thread is expiring after approximately 10ms?

Comment: Yes that would be suboptimal but Task.Run uses the thread pool. 200 tasks per second are completely harmless. This appears to consume about 2 CPU cores on average. Totally OK.

Comment: last question I promise! Do you know if the AsyncCallback for UdpClient.BeginReceive is executing on a separate thread? generally speaking, async = new thread?

Comment: It executes on the thread pool. The BCL async APIs all execute there. If you don't like that you can marshal the call to any place you like.